# No visible @interfacefor 'NSNumber' declares the selector initwithInt.' error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am making a quiz app with several different categories. I have a few more things to do but I am running into the error in the title. Here is what my code looks like so far

```
-(IBAction)Category1:(id)sender{

    Category1.hidden = YES;
    Category2.hidden = YES;
    Question.hidden = NO;

    Answer1.hidden = NO;
    Answer2.hidden = NO;
    Answer3.hidden = NO;
    Answer4.hidden = NO;

    Right1.hidden = YES;
    Right2.hidden = YES;
    Right3.hidden = YES;
    Right4.hidden = YES;

    Wrong1.hidden = YES;
    Wrong2.hidden = YES;
    Wrong3.hidden = YES;
    Wrong4.hidden = YES;

    SelectCategory.hidden = YES;

    NSMutableArray *questionArray = [[NSMUTABLEArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
        [questionArray addObject:[NSNumber alloc] initwithInt:i]];  // Here is where the error occurs
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        int randomIndex = arc4random() % [questionArray count];
        int Category1Question = [[questionArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex] intValue];
        [questionArray removeObjectAtIndex:randomIndex];
        switch (Category1Question) {
            case 0:
            Question.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Question here"];
            Right1.hidden = NO;
            Wrong2.hidden = NO;
            Wrong3.hidden = NO;
            Wrong4.hidden = NO;
            Answer1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Correct answer here"];
            Answer2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong answer here"];
            Answer3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong answer here"];
            Answer4.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wrong answer here"];
            break;
            case 1:
            // etc etc all the way to case 99

           default:
               break;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure this out at all. Please if anyone could help and explain it to me I would really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: initwithInt is a typo - you may want to use initWithInt (note the capitalisation).

Comment: `initWithInt` with a CAPITAL W.

Comment: When in doubt, check the documentation!!!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `initwithInt:` but there is an `initWithInt:`, Objective-C is case sensitive.

And your `[` are placed wrongly:

```
 [questionArray addObject:[NSNumber alloc] initwithInt:i]];
```

should be:

```
 [questionArray addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:i]];
```

Or even better:

```
 [questionArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
```

Comment: Okay, so the error is gone, but it isn't working how I was hoping. I run the app, and I select the category. I get to the questions, and when I answer a question, it goes blank. It doesn't go to the next case which would be the next question. As far as my original question goes I guess its fixed, but the whole purpose of me trying the use the NSMutableArray was to create an int with a switch to go from one question to the next within the same category. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[questionArray addObject:@(i)];
```

Comment: That fixed the problem, but when I run the quiz it doesn't continue to the next question. I am trying to integrate the NSMutableArray with a switch that will help me move from one question in a specific category of 100 questions to the next question within that same category. I have 5 categories that are all in the question.m as "-(IBAction)"Different Categories":(id)sender{" but I have only been able to return to the category selection menu instead of straight to the next question. I also want to be able to return to the main menu after all questions have been completed.